# ons-button ng-click is not useful

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

This is my code

```
<ons-button modifier="large" id="btnLogin" 
     ng-click="navMain()" class="login-button">login</ons-button>
```

When I use it in safari on ios8.4, it doesn't work. I click the button, it is not useful, please help.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug in Fastclick library that Onsen UI uses internally. Update Onsen UI to the last version (1.3.8 right now) where this library was also updated and fixed.

Related:
https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/858
https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/851

Comment: Thank you very much,by update osnenui to v1.8.3,the button can work.